# Laravel 5.4 e Dompdf - problemas?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, dompdf

Estou tentando gerar um PDF à partir de uma `view`, e está dando certo, porém, quando eu chamo a rota pra chamar o `controller`, o carregamento fica por vários segundos, até minutos pra gerar o PDF, e fazer o download, sem falar que não está aplicando os meus estilos CSS. Gostaria de uma luz, pra saber o que eu posso fazer.

***PS: usar outra library, somente se for mais simples.***

***View:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Lista de chamada</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h4>Lista de chamada</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body text-center">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Cartão SUS</th>
                                <th>Data de nascimento</th>
                                <th>Avaliação alterada</th>
                                <th>Peso</th>
                                <th>Altura</th>
                                <th>Assinatura</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($pacientes as $paciente)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $paciente->NumeroCartaoSUS }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $paciente->DataNascimento }}</td>
                                        <td>{!!
                                                $paciente->AvaliacaoAlterada == 1 ?
                                                    Icon::ok().' Sim' :
                                                    Icon::remove().' Não'
                                            !!}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{ $paciente->Peso }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $paciente->Altura }}</td>
                                        <td>  </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Controller:***

```
<?php

namespace Famerp\Http\Controllers\PDF;

use PDF;
use Famerp\Models\Paciente;
use Famerp\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PDFController extends Controller
{
    public function pdfListaChamada()
    {
        $pacientes = Paciente::all();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.pdf-lista-chamada', array('pacientes' => $pacientes));
        return $pdf->setPaper('a4')->download('lista-chamada.pdf');
    }
}
```

Segui as orientações de código que tem na própria página do `GitHub` do projeto, não entendo do porquê disso.

Comment: Se tem o endereço desse código? acho que CSS e Font tem algumas configurações e o tempo de geração também está muito alto devido talvez fatores que não podemos reproduzir

Comment: Github do projeto tem um link correto? qual link é?

Comment: O link do projeto do PDF é esse: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

O link do meu projeto é esse: https://github.com/matheuspicioli/famerp

Comment: Possui muitos pacientes? Esse link é tem a compatibilidade do CSS https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility

Comment: Realmente olhando assim, sem saber o que acontece na sua máquina parece correto, o código é pequeno e limpo, mas, vai saber o porque do problema, é aquilo não tem como reproduzir, é um problema local talvez.

Comment: Ta espera um pouco, coloque no git a tabela então. fico no aguardo.

Comment: descobri o problema

Comment: E qual é? É envolvendo ambiente mesmo?

Comment: O arquivo de css, ele não está aceitando, deve ai ter uma razão. principalmente por causa das fontes retire `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` do seu arquivo `View` e teste

Comment: Agora está funcionando, mas por que ele não reconhece meu css?

Comment: Porque não é seu é de um framework e o mesmo não é compatível com o algoritmo do gerador pdf. As fontes por exemplo são algumas como descrito na documentação.

Comment: Então pra aplica um CSS, eu preciso retirar dele as fontes, ou somente usar o caminho relativo, em vez da função que o Laravel me disponibiliza?

Comment: Você tem que usar as fontes e os css compativel com o pacote, e nele inclusive vem explicado isso... entendeu? Daquele CSS não adianta usar!

Comment: Foi resolvido, tirando a função asset() e chamando através do caminho relativo mesmo, isso resolveu o tempo de geração do PDF, mas a fonte glyphicon não foram possíveis carrega-los. Obrigado!!

Answer (score -1):

Uma recomendação para PDF com Laravel que dou é usar as bibliotecas "barryvdh/laravel-snappy" "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64" e "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64" em minha opinião é a melhor forma de gerar PDF no Laravel.

PS.: Até o momento não tive nenhum problema com compatibilidade de CSS, imagens etc

Exemplo:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Comment: não adianta indicar para usar determinadas bibliotecas se não informar um exemplo mínimo. Edite sua resposta e acrescente esse detalhe, vai ajudar a todos.